# How to change a value from a parent component using Vue 3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

There are two components, a parent component, and the child component.

I passed the parent component's variable to the child component like below.

When I change the selectbox value in the child component, I got

```
Set operation on key "selectedScopes" failed: target is readonly.
```

How can I change the value from the parent component?

```
// Parent component
<template>
  <q-page class="wrap-page">
    <q-input
      label="Punch No."
      v-model="editedItem.number"
    ></q-input>
    <PunchScope
      :scopes="scopes"
      :selectedScopes="editedItem.selectedScopes"
      @updateSelectedScopes="updateSelectedScopes"
    ></PunchScope>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import { api } from '../../boot/axios'
import PunchScope from '../../components/punch/PunchScope'

export default {
  components: {
    PunchScope
  },

  setup () {
    const editedItem = reactive({
      id: '',
      number: '',
      selectedScopes: []
    })

    const scopes = ref([])

    onMounted(async () => {
      api.get(`/punches/${editedItem.id}`)
        .then(response => {
          Object.assign(editedItem, response.data.punch)
          scopes.value = response.data.scopes
        })
    })

    const updateSelectedScopes = (selectedScopes) => {
      api.post(`/punches/${editedItem.id}/scopes`, { selectedScopes: selectedScopes })
        .then(response => {
          editedItem.selectedScopes = response.data.punch.selectedScopes
        })
    }

  return {
    editedItem,
    updateSelectedScopes,
    selectedScopes
  }
}
</script>

// Child Component
<template>
  <q-select
    label="Select punch scopes"
    v-model="selection"
    use-input
    use-chips
    multiple
    input-debounce="0"
    :options="scopes"
  >
    <template v-slot:after>
      <q-btn
        round
        dense
        flat
        icon="send"
        @click="updateSelectedScopes"
      />
    </template>
  </q-select>
</template>

<script>
import { toRef } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: ['scopes', 'selectedScopes'],
  emites: ['updateSelectedScopes'],

  setup (props, { emit }) {
    const selection = toRef(props, 'selectedScopes')

    const updateSelectedScopes = () => {
      emit('updateSelectedScopes', selection.value)
    }

    return {
      updateSelectedScopes,
      selection
    }
  }
}
</script>
```